# Nginx - custom login page

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to secure my webapp by using nginx base authentication.

What I'm looking for is a way to  force the browser to show my custom html login page instead of the default login popup but still handle the authorization process.

I try to omit the 'WWW-Authenticate' header and the popup wasn't display but I've no idea how to force the browser to add the 'Authorization' header for each request.

hereby nginx.conf:

```
location /{
            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080/;
            error_page 401  /login.html;
    }

    location = /login.html {
            root html;
    more_clear_headers 'WWW-Authenticate';              
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `proxy_intercept_errors on;` or you will not be able to define `error_page`. Otherwise NGINX just passes the HTTP 401 response back to the client.

```
location /{
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080/;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 401  /login.html;
}

location = /login.html {
    root html;
    more_clear_headers 'WWW-Authenticate';              
}
```

> Syntax:   proxy_intercept_errors on | off;
> Default: proxy_intercept_errors off;
> Context:  http, server, location
> Determines whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be intercepted and redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive.

Answer (score 0):

*has* to be a better way to accomplish this, but i managed to do it with X-Accel-Redirect and php, here's how:

i wanted to have a custom login page for folder /foo/ (and recursively all its content)

... first i renamed the on-disk folder `/var/www/html/foo` to `/var/www/html/internal_foo` , then i added to nginx config:

```
location ~ /internal_foo {
        internal;
        # even if this is the default root, the internal-directive seems to prevent inheriting the root directive, so have to explicitly specify it here...
        root /var/www/html;
}
location ~ /foo {
        try_files "" /foo.php$is_args$args;
}
```

then i created a `/var/www/html/foo.php` with the contents:

```
<?php
// warning: script vulnerable to timing attack which can disclose existence of files. (realpath() is not constant-time)
if(is_authorised()){
    $translated="/internal_foo/".urldecode(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],strlen("/foo/")));
        $file=__DIR__.$translated;
        $file=realpath($file);
        if(false===$file){http_response_code(404);exit();}
        if(0!==strpos($file,__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."internal_foo")){
                // probably a hacker attempting ../../../etc/passwd schenanigans.
                http_response_code(400);
                exit();
        }
        header("X-accel-redirect: ".$translated);
}else{
        show_loginpage();
}
```

and voila, if a user is authorized, the request is sent to nginx, otherwise `show_loginpage();` is executed (where you can put your custom login page), mission accomplished :)

Answer (score -3):

If you really want to do this. The easiest way is to put the username and password into the url. Basic Authentication supports this. Change all requests to the format below and it will work:

```
"http://" + username + ":" + password + "@example.com"
```

Comment: thanks, can you please give an example of nginx configuration file for such implementation, I can't ask the user to add the u/p to the url so I guess it has to be internally via session.

Comment: I think you would have to handle it client side, use JS to grab username and  password and use it changing the window.location.href

Comment: i think op wanna do something like this https://github.com/shopware/devdocs/blob/master/source/blog/_posts/2015-03-02-sso-with-nginx-auth_request.md. Posting user/pass as part of url is totally un-secure in modern world